# 'imeOptions' not working when define 'digits' in XML

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

In my Android App, I want to let user to type Full Name at one point to an EditText. There I need the following behaviour

1). Should NOT allow user to type invalid characters. For that I was using the following

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
```

2). The keyboard should have the "ActionNext" to easily move to next Field. For that I was using the following

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

But when I specify ***digits*** as above, it looses the ActionNext and instead get **Enter Key** (move 2nd line)...

My full xml is as follows,

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText_FullName"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    android:maxLength="40"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:typeface="normal"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:lines="1"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>
```

I found after searching in google it saying to use `android:singleLine="true"` to fix the issue. Yes that fix issue but this attribute is ***deprecated*** and and Android Studio suggests to use `android:maxLines="1"` which again NOT fix the issue and loose ActionNext in Keyboard. Basically instead of ActionNext I still see Enter key (move next line) option.

Has anyone got a solution for this. Thanks

**Edits**

I could use regular expression validation or register the EditText to a  KeyListener. But looking for a pure xml solution.

Comment: Seems that the only way is to add `android:singleLine="true"`. It is deprecated but you can use it until they fix the issue